# Loop through TextBox and get TextBox number

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have 7 textbox corresponding to 7 labels without userform.
1.I need to loop though each textbox and find the empty/blank textbox
2.Display a msgbox for the corresponding label.caption that it is cannot be empty
 3.Find the textbox number to set focus on the blank textbox

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To 7
'Find the empty/blank TextBox
If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox" & x).Object.Text = "" Then
'Display Message
MsgBox ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Label" & x).Object.Caption & " cannot be empty"
'Find the empty/blank Texbox number to set focus.This is where I am stuck 
TextBox(Number?).Activate
Exit Sub
End If
Next x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim emptyTextboxIndex As Long
For x = 1 To 7
    If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox" & x).Object.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Label" & x).Object.Caption & " cannot be empty"
        emptyTextboxIndex = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox" & x).Index
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(emptyTextboxIndex).Activate
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next x
```

On a side note, if I were you, I would avoid using `ActiveSheet` and I would use an explicit reference to the worksheet. I would also avoid using `Exit Sub`.